# dreamt of or dreamt

Tags: relative-pronouns

> 1. His house was on the same beach he had dreamt of.
> 2. His house was on the same beach he had dreamt.

The first sentence is from a test. I am doubtful that
the writer wish to dream of a house, not the beach.
He will buy a house on the beach [on which] he dream.
 Which one is suitable, "dreamt of" or "dreamt"?

Answer (score 3):

Ordinarily (there are occasional exceptions in literary use), *dream* is intransitive—we dream *of* or *about* something.

A relative clause follows the constituent which it modifies, so the relative clause (with the relativizer *that* or *which* deleted) *he had dreamt of* cannot modify *house*; it has to modify *the same beach*.

'He' at some point had a 'dream' of a beach—without more context we can't know whether this was an actual dream or a figurative dream, a wish. At some later point he encounters a house which is located on that very beach.

Comment: It is from "Dreams Do Come True" by Jim Bishop.

Comment: @learner Ah, in the story what he dreamed of was specifically [a house on that beach], so what you want to write is something like *His house was on that beach, just as he had dreamed*.

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret these two sentences slightly differently.

> His house was on the same beach he had dreamt of.

In this case, I'd imagine that someone had a long-term goal of building a house on a specific beach, and one day his dream came true.

> His house was on the same beach he had dreamt.

In this case, I would think that someone had a dream while they were sleeping, about a house on a beach, and there was an actual house on that same beach as in the dream.

The word *dream* can refer to a long-term goal (e.g., *I dream of being a published author someday*), or to the (often strange) things we see in our mind while sleeping (e.g., *last night I dreamed we were driving our car through a jungle*).

I don’t think I can strongly state that “dreamt of” always means long-term goals, while “dreamt” without the “of” always refers to visions during sleep. But that’s how I initially interpret those two sentences without any further context provided.

Answer (score 0):

*Dream* is roughly logically similar to *invent in your mind*:

> I dreamed a beach ≈ I invented a beach in my mind.

(*Up* can be used to emphasize or clarify this meaning of *dream* - "I dreamed up a beach" - and this will never mean the type of dreams you have while sleeping.)

*Dream of X* is roughly logically similar to *think of something involving X*

> I dreamed of a beach ≈ I thought about something where a beach was involved.

You can see from the above why almost always you want to say *dream of X* if X is a setting, background, or something previously existing.